# A coefficent capable of computing a unique value for each shape, for classifying them based on some characteristics

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory

I have multiple types of shapes, like this [shape 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ0b3.png), [shape 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHPA.png), [shape 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWIX.png), and there are plenty more shapes, form 3D coordinates. All of these shapes come from a [reference shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTkt2.png), and they are deformed by a set of transformation. A first classifier that is capable of giving a value if the shapes move in a [symmetric way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ0b3.png) or [antisimetric way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHPA.png). And then how much they are regular,[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRFsU.png) with rispect to [this shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHPA.png).

I need a way to automatically assign a value to each shape based on some of its characteristics. What can be used to classify the different shapes?

I expect that by taking the shape, it obtains a scalar value associated with it. For example, the Hausdorff distance from the reference shape. From the classification I aspect, the value is capable of identifying a unique shape with a unique number. The objective of the classification is to trace all the shapes that are similar

I apologize in advance for the lack of rigor in the question.

Comment: In each branch from the central note there are 3 pieces. Are corresponding links of the same length? [meaning e.g. the 3 connected to central node all same]

Comment: In the reference, yes. And then, after the transformation, the links change length

Comment: If the transformation can change the lengths, it is not clear one could identify the individual links before and after the change. [I mean there would be three ways to set up which of the three transformed branches from center corresponds to which from the reference figure.] Then of course there would be the differing lengths and angles.

Comment: If I drop the fact that I want only a scalar value, but, for example, a mix of values that identify the symmetry, the length, and the angle? I need an approximate way to identify the varius shape

Comment: For the picture called "symmetric" there is a vertical line which one can reflect the figure across and obtain a map from figure to itself. But for the one called "antisymmetric" there is nothing like that, and it is not clear what you mean by calling a figure antisymmetric. [this remark is aimed at some thigs in the original question] In your last comment you say you could work with several values. There are a lot of ways to do that, one trivial one: give coordinates of each node in the figure. But if one wants to rely on just segment lengths and angles, I can't see a natural way to do it.

Comment: You're right It is improper to use symmetic and antysimmetric in this case. But nevertheless, my objective is to identify some characteristics that could also be the coordinates, to make each shape unice with respect to the other, but at the same time capable of finding a general distition, which may be a type of entropy with respect to the initial configuration. The links are more than three. The pictures are just an example to make understandable, at least I hope, the problem.